# Why Flutter App crashing on some devices?

Tags: android, flutter, crash, crashlytics

I just published 2 different Flutter apps. and they are crashing on some devices upon inquiry and Implementing crashlytics i found
1)io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary
2)io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.nativeUpdateRefresh

these to reason devices such as
OnePlus8Pro

i searched but haven't found asy satisfactory solution and the reason it would be great if someone can provide the reason for this and any solution